# list multiplication creates aliased lists instead of separate entities as other types

Tags: python, list, multiplication

Why does this creates aliased arrays ?!! is this a expected behavior ?

```
In [57]: p=[[]] * 3

In [58]: p[0].append(2)

In [59]: p
Out[59]: [[2], [2], [2]]
```

Comment: It is full copy of `p = [list()] * 3` which creates single instance of `list` and copy reference to this instance 3 times. Yes, **it is** expected behaviour. To do what you want you can use list comp: `[[] for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: yeah i used range and for